# filling a data frame with N count for two distinct categories

Tags: pandas, group-by

sample data:

```
type1 = ['bunny','cow','pig','chicken','elephant']
type2 = ['flower','tree','grass']

data_type1 = np.random.choice(a = type1, p = [0.05,0.15,0.25,0.05,0.5], size=1000)
data_type2 = np.random.choice(a = type2, p = [0.25,0.25,0.50], size=1000)
data_value = stats.poisson.rvs(loc = 18, mu = 30, size = 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'type1':data_type1,'type2':data_type2,'data':data_value})

grp1 = pd.unique(df.type1.values)
grp1.sort()
grp2 = pd.unique(df.type2.values)
grp2.sort()
m_df = pd.DataFrame(index = grp1,columns=grp2)
```

given a df structured as 'df', how would I populate 'm_df' with the count of each type combo. I want to accomplish `df.groupby(['type1','type2'])['data'].count()` but I'm not sure how to write it into a df so it looks nice and is more useful.

Edit: below is a simpler df that also works as an example. The expected output is the number of values for each type combination -- the exact output shown when the input is `df.groupby(['type1','type2'])['data'].count()`. The question is how to represent that output as a dataframe resembling m_df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type1': ['bunny','cow','pig','chicken','elephant','cow','pig'],
           'data': [32,23,45,35,20,28,55],
           'type2':['female', 'male','male','male','male','female','female']})
```

Comment: `data_value` can't be reproduced. Can you give an example _as text_ and show a clear expected output ?

Comment: The actual values aren't important, only the structure of the df, but sure: `df = pd.DataFrame({'type1': ['bunny','cow','pig','chicken','elephant','cow','pig'],
           'data': [32,23,45,35,20,28,55],
           'type2':['female', 'male','male','male','male','female','female']})`

Comment: Can you add it in your question + the expected output as well ?

Comment: You're expecting an output that respect the format of `m_df` but you say nothing about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `value_counts` (same as `groupby_count`) then `unstack` the second index level:

```
>>> (df.value_counts(['type1', 'type2'])
       .unstack('type2', fill_value=0)
       .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

          female  male
bunny          1     0
chicken        0     1
cow            1     1
elephant       0     1
pig            1     1
```

You can also use `pd.crosstab` or `pivot_table`:

```
>>> (pd.crosstab(df['type1'], df['type2'], 1, aggfunc='count')
   .fillna(0).astype(int).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

>>> (df.assign(val=1).pivot_table('val', 'type1', 'type2', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have used the input what you provided.

I don't know, what you are trying to achieve here but from what I feel you required is.

The code???

```html
df_grp = df.groupby(['type1','type2'], as_index=False)['data'].count()
```

The output looks like this

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0xCZ.png)